# Trying to create a sorted list based on another list using a function

Tags: c

Can someone solve it for me?

This code creates 2 different lists `mylist` in which the words have no specific order and `yourlist` in which the words are linked to the list in alphabetical order by insertincr.

The words are read from a `txt` file so if u want to test create one.

Now i want to do the following task:

Im trying to write a `function` which creates a `new list` based on `yourlist` which is its `argument` ,and the new list is the sorted version based on the word lenght ,of the input list(`yourlist`).Then both lists are printed.

I want to do it without using any other ready functions and i( want to do it `recursively`.

I cant think of any way to make it work.

An output of the code below is:

HELLOTHERETHEREMYFRIENDATcalled with empty list

called with empty list

00690DE8

called with empty list

duplicated

AT: FRIEND: HELLO: MY: THERE:

00690F50

HELLO: THERE: THERE: MY: FRIEND: AT:

DiffrentWords==Listlenght: 5

TotalWords==ListlenghtplusOCCURS==TextWords: 6

and an output after i call the `createlenbasedlst` should be:

AT: MY: HELLO: THERE: FRIEND:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct box {
    char value[20] ;
    struct box * next ; 
    int occurs;
} ;
typedef struct box Box;
typedef Box * List;

Box * createbox(char a[]);
void appendref( Box ** start_ptrptr,Box * node_ptr);
void appendrefrec( Box ** start_ptrptr,Box *  node_ptr);
void insertincr( List * list_ptr, Box *  node_ptr);
void report(Box *mylist_ptr);
void printall(FILE *);
int lenlist(List lst);
int lenmylist(List lst);

int main( ) {
    List mylist = NULL; 
    List yourlist = NULL;
    //List newlist =NULL;
    char buffer[20]="";
    FILE *text;
    text=fopen("TEXT.txt","rt");
    printall(text);
    rewind(text);
for(;fscanf(text,"%s",buffer)!=EOF;){
    Box * new_ptr ;
    Box * your_new_ptr;
    new_ptr = createbox(buffer) ;
    your_new_ptr = createbox(buffer) ;

    appendref( & mylist , new_ptr) ; 
    insertincr(& yourlist, your_new_ptr);


}

    report(yourlist);

    report(mylist);

    printf("\n\nDiffrentWords==Listlenght:% d",lenlist(yourlist));
    printf("\n\nTotalWords==ListlenghtplusOCCURS==TextWords:% d",lenmylist(yourlist));

    return 0;
}

Box * createbox(char a[20]) {
    Box * newBox_ptr;
    newBox_ptr = malloc( sizeof (Box) ) ;
    strcpy((newBox_ptr -> value),a);
    newBox_ptr -> next = NULL;
    newBox_ptr -> occurs= 0;
    return newBox_ptr;
}


void report(Box *mylist_ptr) {
    if (mylist_ptr == NULL) {
        return ;
    }

    printf("%s: ", mylist_ptr->value);
    report(mylist_ptr->next);

    return ;    
}

void appendref( Box ** start_ptrptr, 
                Box *  node_ptr
              ) {
    Box * iter = * start_ptrptr;
    if ( iter == NULL ) {
        printf("called with empty list\n");
        *start_ptrptr = node_ptr;
        return ;        }
    for ( ; iter->next != NULL ; 
    iter = iter->next  ) ;

    iter->next = node_ptr;

return ;    
}

void appendrefrec( Box ** start_ptrptr, 
                Box *  node_ptr) {
    Box * iter = * start_ptrptr;

    if ( iter == NULL ) {
        printf("called with empty list\n");
        *start_ptrptr = node_ptr;
        return ;    
    }

    appendrefrec( & (iter->next) , node_ptr);

return ;    
}


void insertincr( List * list_ptr, 
                Box *  node_ptr
              ) {
    Box * iter = * list_ptr;
    if ( iter == NULL ) {
        printf("called with empty list\n");
        * list_ptr = node_ptr;
        return ;
    }
    if (strcmp(iter->value,node_ptr->value)==0){
        printf("duplicated\n");
        iter->occurs++;
        free(node_ptr);
        return ;
    }
    if (strcmp(iter->value,node_ptr ->value)<0) {
        insertincr(  &(iter->next), node_ptr);
        return ;    
    }

    if (strcmp(iter->value,node_ptr ->value)>0) {

        node_ptr -> next = *list_ptr;
        *list_ptr = node_ptr;

        return ;
    }
}
void printall(FILE *text){
    char word[20]="";
    for(;fscanf(text,"%s",word)!=EOF;){
        printf("%s",word);
    }
    return;
}

int lenlist(List lst){
    if(lst==NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1+lenlist(lst->next);/*or return lst?(1+lenlist(lst->next)):0;*/
}

int lenmylist(List lst){
    if(lst==NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    return (1+lenmylist(lst->next)+(lst->occurs));
}


//MY ATTEMP   
void createlenbasedlst(List lst,List *newlist){
if (*newlist==NULL){
    *newlist=createbox(lst->value);
    (*newlist)->occurs=lst->occurs;
    createlenbasedlst(lst->next,newlist);
    return;
}
Box *iter = *newlist;
if (iter!=NULL&&strlen(iter->value)<strlen(lst->value))
    createlenbasedlst(lst,&(iter->next));
else
    if (lst!=NULL&&strlen(iter->value)>=strlen(lst->value)){
        Box *temp = *newlist;
        *newlist=createbox(lst->next->value);
        (*newlist)->occurs=lst->next->occurs;
        (*newlist)->next=temp;
        createlenbasedlst(lst->next,&(iter->next));
    }
    return;
}

return;
}
//attemp 2
void createlenbasedlst(List *newlist,List lst){
    Koutaki *iter=NULL;
    while(lst&&iter==NULL){
        Koutaki *temp = *newlist;
        *newlist = createkoutaki(lst->value);
        *newlist->occurs=lst->occurs;
        *newlist->next = temp;
        lst=lst->next;
    }
    if (iter==NULL){
        iter=*newlist;
        lst=iter->next;
    }
    while(iter){
        if(strlen(iter->value)<strlen(lst->value)){
            createlenbasedlst(&iter,lst->next);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to format the output - an imposible muddle of comment and output.

Comment: Try erasing the parts where memory location gets printed.Idk i just want some help ,i would be gratefull sir.I'll correct my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `while` loop instead of `for` loop in this case. Just walk the source list `yourlist` and insert in to `newlist` without additional sort.

The additional `typedef` for `List` is confusing, you can just use `Box*` or pick a better name like `node*`

```
void copy(Box* source, Box **dest)
{
    if(!source)
        return;

    Box *ptr = malloc(sizeof(Box));
    strcpy(ptr->value, source->value);
    ptr->occurs = source->occurs;
    ptr->next = *dest;
    *dest = ptr;

    copy(source->next, dest);
}

int main() 
{
    List yourlist = NULL;
    char buffer[20] = "";
    FILE *text = fopen("TEXT.txt", "rt");

    printall(text);
    rewind(text);
    while(fscanf(text, "%s", buffer) != EOF)
    {
        Box *ptr = createbox(buffer);
        insertincr(&yourlist, ptr);
    }

    List newlist = NULL;
    copy(yourlist, &newlist);

    report(yourlist);
    report(newlist);
    return 0;
}
```

---

This is the cleaned up version copying list with sorted insert and recursive functions. Note that this is using a recursive function within another recursive function (`copy` and `insert`). This should be avoided in practice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_t
{
    char value[20];
    struct node_t* next;
    int occurs;
} node;

void insert(node **list, node* ptr)
{
    node *iter = *list;
    if(iter == NULL)
    {
        *list = ptr;
        return;
    }

    //call strcmp only once, use `test` value several times
    int test = strcmp(iter->value, ptr->value);

    if(test == 0)
    {
        iter->occurs++;
        free(ptr);
    }
    else if(test < 0)
    {
        insert(&iter->next, ptr);
    }
    else if(test > 0)
    {
        ptr->next = *list;
        *list = ptr;
    }
}

//recursive copy
void copy(node **dest, node* source)
{
    if(!source)
        return;
    node *ptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
    strcpy(ptr->value, source->value);
    ptr->occurs = source->occurs;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    //recursive insert, don't expand this function
    insert(dest, ptr);

    copy(dest, source->next);
}

void report(node *list)
{
    for(node *it = list; it; it = it->next)
        printf("%s, ", it->value);
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    //call srand() too
    node* list1 = NULL;
    node* list2 = NULL;
    char buffer[20];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "%d", rand() % 100);
        node *ptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
        strcpy(ptr->value, buffer);
        ptr->next = NULL;
        ptr->occurs = 0;
        insert(&list1, ptr);
    }

    copy(&list2, list1);

    report(list1);
    report(list2);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Fix for you own function

```
void insert_sorted(List *list, Box* ptr)
{
    Box *iter = *list;
    if(iter == NULL)
    {
        *list = ptr;
        return;
    }

    //sort by length:
    int test = strlen(iter->value) - strlen(ptr->value);

    //sort by length:
    //int test = strcmp(iter->value, ptr->value);

    if(test == 0)
    {
        iter->occurs++;
        free(ptr);
    }
    else if(test < 0)
    {
        insert_sorted(&iter->next, ptr);
    }
    else if(test > 0)
    {
        ptr->next = *list;
        *list = ptr;
    }
}

//recursive function:
void createlenbasedlst(List *dest, Box* source)
{
    if(!source)
        return;
    Box *ptr = malloc(sizeof(Box));
    strcpy(ptr->value, source->value);
    ptr->occurs = source->occurs;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    //another recursive function. Don't expand in to this function
    insert_sorted(dest, ptr);

    createlenbasedlst(dest, source->next);
}
```